# JSON returned from php is [obejct Object] and jQuery.parseJSON is null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

In my php file I have:

```
$arr[] = array("status"=>0);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

In my javascript, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    initialize(); 
    $("#searchbutton").click(function(){

    var usrinput = $("#userinput").val();

    $.get(
        "searchpageajaxjson.php",
        {searchterm: usrinput},
        function(data){
            searchreturned(data);
        },
        "json"
    ); 
    });
 });


function searchreturned(data){
   console.log(data); 
   var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   console.log(parsed); 
   //for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {  
    //            alert(parsed[i]);  
    //     } 
   //    
}
```

The console.log(data) shows [object Obejct]
and console.log(parsed) shows null

Where am I going wrong?

Edited to Add:

alert(data.status) shows undefined.

Second Edit:

I'm really grateful for all the help I've received. It's hard to pick an answer, because I'm really only able to move on from this problem due to all the help received in all the comments. I am always in awe of you kind folks who give your time to helping newbies like myself.

Comment: Can you please share the json as text and the [Object object]?

Comment: What console are you using? It should show the object properties.

Comment: You jumped from using `$.` as the jQuery identifier and then to `jQuery.` - any reason? `$.parseJSON` would have worked too...

Comment: @Esailija. This is the first time I am doing this - I opened up the developer tools on the browser (IE) and there is a console tab which shows the following: LOG: [object Object] 
LOG: null

Comment: @OscarJara, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: try `alert(data.status)` - see if that pops up a value.

Comment: @Lix perhaps it is because I am cobbling together code trying to make this work. :( I am having trouble understanding jquery and json. I will try replacing jQuery with $.

Comment: @Lix alert(data.status) gives me undefined.

Comment: Do I not have the array created properly in the php?

Comment: "[object Object]" is what happens when you coerce a JS object to a string. Thi susually happens when you use "alert" and I con't remember right now if IE's console.log does that too. You might want to try to debug the code in a different browser (chrome comes with a great builtin console/debugger) or yo umight want to set a global variable with your object and tell IE to inspect that variable.

Comment: @missingno I tried the console in Chrome, and it's much nicer, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to call `jQuery.parseJSON` on `data` again. jQuery takes care of that for you already, since you used `"json"` as the `dataType`.

Comment: Would it make a difference if I said even before attemping to use parse.JSON, alert(data.status) is saying undefined?

Comment: @ValerieParker: Yes, it would. Make sure the PHP outputs no warnings or other cruft apart from the JSON.

Comment: That echo json_encode($arr) statement is the only echo statement. I do have this sort of thing as well: if (!$connection){
 die('Not connected: '.mysql_error());
}

Comment: @ValerieParker: Yes, it would, if there was an error. Or, if you have warnings and such turned on, other problems could be causing it too. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @ValerieParker: Also, `alert(data.status)` isn't the right one. Try `alert(data[0].status)` instead.

Comment: alert(data[0].status) does give the correct value, 0. Can you point me to any resources where I might better learn how to work with json in javascript? I've been googling all evening, but not finding anything which will give me a really basic unerstanding, with lots of examples.

Comment: @ValerieParker: JSON is just JavaScript objects - any valid JSON is also valid JavaScript. So just look up in your favourite book/website/anything object and array literal syntax in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** There is no reason to call `jQuery.parseJSON` or `$.parseJSON` because jQuery knows that is already a JSON object due to the `"json"` parameter you passed here:

```
$.get('source', {param:param}, function(data){ /*work with data*/ }, "json");
```

**2.** If `console.log(data);` is not null and you are getting some `[Object Object]` try to see what are the properties of that object, like this:

**e.g:** Explore your object:

[image]

**e.g:** Print value from object:

```
//this will output "Horror"
data.genre
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Oscar Jara, thanks, I now understand what you mean. And when I used the Chrome console instead, I can see the values.